# Parse csv file and calculate same data by specific formula

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have CSV file with:

```
block_num,date_time,miner_wallet,rewards,finished,verified
133,2019-02,0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85,0.0,7,6
134,2019-02,0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85,0.0,2,2
135,2019-02,0xd1dacf164f4bed77c37a26a79e9d63606cc35c82,0.0,7,6
135,2019-02,0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85,0.0,7,7
136,2019-02,0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85,0.0,3,3
136,2019-02,0xd1dacf164f4bed77c37a26a79e9d63606cc35c82,0.0,4,4
137,2019-02,0xa57d8b10d0186abf946f9b6a2709c680970fdd39,0.0,1,1
```

I need to calculate each same "miner_wallet" to one output with miner address and sum of last field "verified" and multiplied by 4, so output for will be:

```
0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85 72
0xd1dacf164f4bed77c37a26a79e9d63606cc35c82 40
0xa57d8b10d0186abf946f9b6a2709c680970fdd39 4
```

using bash, awk or any easy way...

Comment: "or any easy way..." -> In [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6) it would be `ipcsv data.csv | group miner_wallet | select name, @{n='check'; e={($_.group | measure verified -sum).sum * 4}} | epcsv out.csv -notype`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do with `awk`. Assuming your first line in your file is your header row you show that simply needs to be skipped, you can do:

```
$ awk -F, '{ if (NR == 1) next; w[$3] += $6 * 4} 
    END { for (i in w) print i, w[i]}' file
0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85 72
0xa57d8b10d0186abf946f9b6a2709c680970fdd39 4
0xd1dacf164f4bed77c37a26a79e9d63606cc35c82 40
```

*Explanation*

- `awk -F,` set the field separator as a `','`
- `'{ if (NR == 1) next;` if the row-number is `1` skip to next row to skip header,
- `w[$3] += $6 * 4}` set the associative array `w[miner_wallet] = verified * 4`
- `END { for (i in w) print i, w[i]}'` output the array indexes and total values.

Comment: Both answers are essentially identical. The only difference is the variable names, where they are initialized and where the check on `NR` is done. `awk` is an awesome tool. Well worth learning..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR>1 {map[$3]+=$6;} END{for (key in map) {print key " " map[key] * 4;}}' i.csv
0x212eccf2cccdecb1880e058ec40b21dd36f47c85 72
0xa57d8b10d0186abf946f9b6a2709c680970fdd39 4
0xd1dacf164f4bed77c37a26a79e9d63606cc35c82 40
```

Where `FS` is the field separator, `map` is a hashmap to hold the sum for each wallet, and `NR>1` skips the first line with the headers.